# Understanding UINavigationController on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is my assumption that every controller which is presented with presentModalViewController:animated: need their own UINavigationController stack for their own hierarchy of drill down controllers? Meaning, say I have a top level controller It has its own navigation stack, and an action button which presents another controller via a modal. That modal has its own navigation stack. Is it best to split each modalView with its own Navigation stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a modal view to have the forward-and-back behavior provided by a navigation controller, you need to provide a separate navigation controller for it.  (If you don't need to push and pop view controllers inside that modal view, then you don't need one, of course.)  This can be a bit of a pain, but them's the breaks.